# Group by inside group by

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

Is it possible to perform a group by inside a group by ?
Actually I have an existing SQL request that returns some data grouping them by the child id. I want to rectify it and display data as is except for certain information that meet a condition, I want to display them by parent ID.
Please note that a parent id may contain several child IDs.
Can you help please
Let s consider the below table :

```
parentID childID value YN AB 
1       | 11     |3   |Y  |A 
1       | 12     |2   |Y  |A 
2       | 13     |8   |Y  |B  
3       | 14     |9   |Y  |A
```

The actual code returns the values that have Y grouped by cildID. What I want is to always return the value column but with an extra condition : If AB = A then return the sum of value grouped by parentID, if not return it as is (grouped by childid)

Comment: you can use group by in sub query and as well as in outer query

Comment: "I want to rectify it and display data as is except for certain information that meet a condition" - this sounds like a HAVING clause

Comment: give us a sample data, expected result and your code.

Comment: Please read this and edit your question accordingly. [Tips for a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557)

Comment: Let s consider the below table :
parentID   childID  value  YN   AB
1               11          3        Y     A
1               12          5        N    A
3               13          7        Y    B
4               14          2        N    A
The actual code returns the values that have Y grouped by cildID.
What I want is to always return the value coluumn but with an extra condition  : If AB = A then return the result grouped by parentID, if not return it as is (grouped by childid)

Comment: group by is used when you have aggregates, like you want an AVG of AB, but for each value of parentID

Comment: also, put the use case in the question itself, and format it so we can read it, easily

Comment: Looks like you want `group by decode('AB','A',parentid,childid)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression on the ChildID column to either return the childID when AB = 'B' or NULL when not, then group by ParentID and the `CASE` expression:

```
with YourData(parentID, childID, value, YN, AB) as (
  select 1, 11, 3, 'Y', 'A' from dual union all 
  select 1, 12, 2, 'Y', 'A' from dual union all 
  select 2, 13, 8, 'Y', 'B' from dual union all  
  select 3, 14, 9, 'Y', 'A' from dual 
)
select parentID
     , case ab when 'B' then childID end childID
     , sum(value) value
  from YourData
 group by parentID
     , case ab when 'B' then childID end
 order by parentID, childID;

 PARENTID    CHILDID      VALUE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1                     5
         2         13          8
         3                     9
```

You can also use a `GROUP BY ROLLUP` to achieve the same result utilizing an appropriate `HAVING` clause:

```
select parentID
     , childID
     , sum(value) value
  from YourData
 group by rollup ((parentID, AB), childID)
having (grouping(childID) = 1 and AB = 'A')
    or (grouping(childID) = 0 and AB = 'B')
 order by parentID, childID;

 PARENTID    CHILDID      VALUE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1                     5
         2         13          8
         3                     9
```